# How does appending to a null string work in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null

I was surprised to see an example of a string being initialised to null and then having something appended to it in a production environment. It just smelt wrong.

I was sure it would have thrown a null object exception but this greatly reduced example also works:

```
string sample = null;
sample += "test";
// sample equals "test"
```

**Note the original code I found sets a string property to null and appends to it elsewhere so answers involving the compiler optimizing out the null at compile-time are irrelevant.*

Can someone explain why this works without error?

### Follow-up:

Based on Leppie's answer I used Reflector to see what is inside string.Concat. It is now really obvious why that conversion takes place (no magic at all):

```
public static string Concat(string str0, string str1)
{
    if (IsNullOrEmpty(str0))
    {
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
        {
            return Empty;
        }
        return str1;
    }
    if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
    {
        return str0;
    }
    int length = str0.Length;
    string dest = FastAllocateString(length + str1.Length);
    FillStringChecked(dest, 0, str0);
    FillStringChecked(dest, length, str1);
    return dest;
}
```

***Note: the specific implementation I was investigating (in the .Net library by Microsoft) does not convert to empty strings as is suggested by the C# standards and most of the answers, but uses a few tests to shortcut the process. The end result is the same as if it did but there you go :)*

Comment: A somewhat unexpected side effect:

    `string sample = null;`
    `sample += null;`
    `//sample == string.Empty`

Then again, I'm not sure what I would have expected `null + null` to be...

Comment: @Timothy: given the source code for `Concat` above, that is exactly what I *would* expect. `IsNullOrEmpty == true` on both parameters returns the `Empty` string constant. Does seem odd though I agree :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

the `+` operator for strings are just shorthand for `string.Concat` which simply turns `null` arguments into empty strings before the concatenation.

**Update:**

The generalized version of string.Concat:

```
public static string Concat(params string[] values)
{
    int num = 0;
    if (values == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    }
    string[] array = new string[values.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        string text = values[i];
        array[i] = ((text == null) ? string.Empty : text);
        num += array[i].Length;
        if (num < 0)
        {
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();
        }
    }
    return string.ConcatArray(array, num);
}
```

Comment: +1: Thanks for that. Based on your answer I decompiled String.Concat (added above) and it all makes sense now. Cheers.

Comment: Obviously this is the right answer for the OP, but was it ever true in .NET that "abc" + null == null? Classically, null is a "non-value", and so operations on a generic "null" are inconclusive. I was always taught that "null isn't empty", and by definition this is correct; null != String.Empty, which is why we have String.IsNullOrEmpty().

Comment: @KeithS, this is simply because the + operator for a string is defined as syntatic sugar to call string.Concat.  If you remove the +operator definition on string, you wouldn't be able to use + at all.  So its not like addition is defined for everything and the compiler magically figures it out (as some languages do).  C# requires an explicit +operator definition to use the operator.

Comment: @Andy: That wasn't the answer to the question I asked. The question was, did .NET's string concatenation ever behave differently than it does currently?

Comment: @HiTechMagic: As per the other answer that should not happen. Was optimization on? What version of .NET?

Comment: @HiTechMagic: When using literal `null`, it gets optimized away, as it can :)

Comment: @HiTechMagic: I think there is a misunderstanding issue here. You should not concern yourself with the internals of `string.Concat`. The way I specified it, is how it behaves. And that is indeed how it is implemented in the generalized version `string.Concat(params string[] values)`.

Comment: I realise I was being pedantic (and that leaving out the .Net tag was a big mistake) :) I will edit my question for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: @Andy Actually, where is the explicit definition of operator+ or operator+= in C# ? People have commented that "+=" is a magical syntactic sugar for string.Concat. I can't help but contrast this with C++'s std::string which explicitly defines all operators for strings, since string isn't a fundamental type in that language.

Comment: @JohanBoule Its in the compiler:  https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/

Answer (score 8):

The relevant citation should be [ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) §14.7.4:

> String concatenation:
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> The binary `+` operator performs string concatenation when one or
>   both operands are of type `string`. **If  an operand of string
>   concatenation is `null`, an empty string is substituted.** Otherwise, any
>   non-string  operand is converted to its string representation by
>   invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type `object`. If
>   `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

Comment: While that was the aim of the language it appears the MS coders were happy to write their logic based on null-ness of the parameters instead (see the decomp above). I guess they felt it was more optimal.

Comment: @HiTech Magic: I believe the implementation matches the specification. Note the text I emphasized: "If an operand [..] is null, an empty string is substituted". Exactly what we see in the behavior and the decompilation.

Comment: Sorry I must be missreading the decomp, as at no point does it *substitute empty strings*. The end result is the same as if it did, and I realise I am just being pedantic, but there you go. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

it is because

> In string concatenation operations, the C# compiler treats a null
>   string the same as an empty string, but it does not convert the value
>   of the original null string.

From [How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

> The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both
>   operands are of type string. If an operand of string concatenation is
>   null, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string
>   argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the
>   virtual ToString method inherited from type object. If ToString
>   returns null, an empty string is substituted.

From [Addition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Where did you get that reference? The "compiler" should have no knowledge of the runtime values. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. Typical that Microsoft's explanation actually makes it more confusing! :)

Comment: @HiTech Magic The compiler does do concatenation of constant values (string literals and the null literal), replacing the concatenation expression with a string literal of the whole string. It also eliminates null literals from concatenation expressions.

Comment: The example is greatly simplified. The actual situation had the null assignment to a member in a constructor, and the += happens much later, so optimisation is not a factor. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is what your code gets compiled to

```
string sample = null;
sample += "test";
```

is compiled to this IL code:

```
.entrypoint
  // Code size       16 (0x10)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string sample)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldstr      "test"
  IL_0009:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_000e:  stloc.0
  IL_000f:  ret
```

And `String.Concat` takes care of NULL string.